# Static type checkers and Language Servers not recognizing attributes of objects that are subclasses

Tags: python, mypy, typing, python-language-server

I apologize if the title looks a bit convoluted, it is a bit difficult to phrase the problem.

Say I am building a graph with nodes and edges. It has a base class `Node` with common attributes to all nodes, and each specific node type can inherit from it extending with more attributes.

Take the following as example with two node types:

```py
from typing import TypeVar


# nodes.py
class Node:
    def __init__(self, base_param: str) -> None:
        self.base_param = base_param

    # other base methods...
        

class NodeType1(Node):
    def __init__(self, base_param: str, node_param_type1: int) -> None:
        super().__init__(base_param)
        self.node_param_type1 = node_param_type1

    # other type1 methods...


class NodeType2(Node):
    def __init__(self, base_param: str, node_param_type2: int) -> None:
        super().__init__(base_param)
        self.node_param_type2 = node_param_type2

    # other type2 methods...


NodeSubClassType = TypeVar("NodeSubClassType", bound=Node)
```

It also has an `Edge` base class with a `source` and a `target`, which are both subclasses of `Node`. Take the following as example with an edge connecting a `NodeType1` to a `NodeType2`.

```py
# edges.py
class Edge:
    def __init__(self, source: NodeSubClassType, target: NodeSubClassType) -> None:
        self.source = source
        self.target = target

    # other base methods...


class EdgeType1ToType2(Edge):
    # Must contain `NodeType1` as `source` and `NodeType2` as `target` when instantiated
    pass
    
    # or add other `type1 to type2` methods
```

My problem is that, whenever I create an instance of `EdgeType1ToType2` passing the correct objects, only the base attribute `base_param` of the `source` and `target` gets recognized by static checkers (I tried `mypy`) and language servers (I tried `pylsp`). For instance, in the following script:

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":

    node_type1 = NodeType1("base_param", 1)
    node_type2 = NodeType2("base_param", 2)
    edge_12 = EdgeType1ToType2(source=node_type1, target=node_type2)

    node_type1.base_param  # this has no issue
    edge_12.source.base_param  # this has no issue
    node_type1.node_param_type1  # this has no issue
    edge_12.source.node_param_type1  # this is not recognized by `mypy` or the LSP
```

If I run `mypy` I get as message

```
error: "NodeSubClassType" has no attribute "node_param_type1"  [attr-defined]
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

only for the `edge_12.source.node_param_type1` line. Also, the language server does not recognize `node_param_type1` as an attribute of `edge_12.source`. Similar issues with `edge_12.target`.

I tried:

- Adding a superfluous `__init__` passing proper parameters to the subclass like

  ```py
  class EdgeType1ToType2(Edge):

      def __init__(self, source: NodeType1, target: NodeType2) -> None:
          super().__init__(source, target)
  ```

  but it does not work.
- and replacing the custom type `NodeSubClassType` with the superclass `Node` directly, but I got the same message with `Node` instead.

I expect a solution that succeeds in static check analysis and possibly gets recognized as valid attribute by language servers.

Comment: Did you mean to say [this](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=master&python=3.11&flags=strict&gist=88c4da22c21118cb44aba7e360308f3a)? I struggle finding a dupe, but it 100% exists on SO, not posting as answer.

Comment: Thanks, @STerliakov, that did the trick! I knew about `Generic` but struggled to find a concrete use, so thanks for showing it. 
I am going to post it as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @STerliakov commented, a possible solution is to create two explicit node types, one to be used as source and another target of an edge:

```py
_Source = TypeVar("_Source", bound=Node)
_Target = TypeVar("_Target", bound=Node)
```

and then create the base edge class like this:

```py
from typing import Generic

class Edge(Generic[_Source, _Target]):
    def __init__(self, source: _Source, target: _Target) -> None:
        self.source = source
        self.target = target

    # other base methods...
```

Then, the concrete subclasses should be created by passing the required node types explicitly:

```py
class EdgeType1ToType2(Edge[NodeType1, NodeType2]):
    # Must contain `NodeType1` as `source` and `NodeType2` as `target` when instantiated
    pass
```

And then, when using the original script

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    node_type1 = NodeType1("base_param", 1)
    node_type2 = NodeType2("base_param", 2)
    edge_12 = EdgeType1ToType2(source=node_type1, target=node_type2)

    node_type1.base_param  # this has no issue
    edge_12.source.base_param  # this has no issue
    node_type1.node_param_type1  # this has no issue
    edge_12.source.node_param_type1  # this has no issue
```

`mypy` shows no issue anymore, and when typing `edge_12.source.` the editor recognizes `node_param_type1` as a valid attribute.